# What text editor should I use with Gitlab and how to install it?

Tags: gitlab, text-editor

I have tried to search online and there was this editor called "Atom". I have never used it before. Is it any good? I have used gedit, sublime text, visual studios and QtReader. I want a text editor like QtReader or visual studios( which shows file directories on the side of the screen) to edit text files from Git bash. Can I install QtReader or VS code for Git bash? If so how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Software recommendations are offtopic for stackoverflow. Besides that, you can use any editor you want to edit text files. I think all of the editors you listed have some sort of git integration. There is no special requirement of git tying it to a specific editor. If you're referring to editing text files in terminal there are `nano`, `vim` and `emacs` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this is not a relevant question but for terminal based you can choose from `vi`, `nano` or `emacs` and for app based you can choose from `vscode`,`sublime text`, `ruby mine`(if working on ruby projects). It's totally a choice based decision.

Comment: Thanks it was rather poorly worded question in retrospect. I was looking for a way to open an editor from the GitBash command line on a windows device. But it turned out not really important. thanks for you answer.